# meta tag server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I am using [react helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and am a bit lost with regards to the server side rendering. If I view elements in google console I can see the title and meta description but when viewing the page source they are not there.

I am using a Node.js backend with express to create an API. The React app is just a frontend application which gets data from the Node.js API.

In React I simply have:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
render() {
   return(
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <title>My site title</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Helmet application" />
        </Helmet>
      </>
    )
}
```

The [direct link](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage) to the server side example shows some code which I don't really know what to do with. I think the word 'server' is throwing me off because I am thinking that I need to put some code on my Node.js server but perhaps that is not the case?

Comment: when you view source its the code that was sent over to your browser from your server will be viewed. Since you are viewing in dev console, and if it appears, then you are all set

Comment: So, are you saying the code in my question is enough for search engines to pick up my title and meta description?

Comment: ah, oops you should see that in source in case of SSR

Comment: Sorry, what is SSR?

Comment: Server Side Rendering

Comment: That was my question, how do I go about setting up the server side rendering. Do I do it in React or Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `Helmet.renderStatic()` method will collect all tags corresponding to the page you are requesting.

If you want to see those tags on the server side as well (source code), you need to, in your server file:

1. Call `const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()`
2. From `helmet` get `helmet.title.toString()` and `helmet.meta.toString()`
3. Append those to your HTML just like https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage `As string input` describes.

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro. When you say "in your server file", are you referring to the Node.js API backend I am running? I am using React to get data from an API and render it on the frontend.

Comment: So you are not running your frontend in the server side. It's just an API you are using. Then do you need those tags to be on the page source. I guess the question is, do you need SSR?

Comment: I have no idea, that is why I asked this question on stack overflow. I want search engines to pick up my titles/meta tags etc. but with my current implementation I don't think they will.

Comment: I asure you they will, google is using the latest version of chrome to crawl websites. https://searchengineland.com/google-will-ensure-googlebot-runs-the-latest-version-of-chromium-316534 So all you can see, they can as well.

Comment: Okay, so what is the point of the server side rendering that helmet React offers if you don't need it for google to see the meta tags?

Comment: In case you still want to implement it, here is a step by step guide https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering/

Comment: React helmet offers you a way to inject any tag into the `head` from any react component in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Change **index.html** to **index.php** and use PHP in **index.php** after build. and create a file ***myMata.php*** move all old meta tags to ***myMata.php*** and make dynamic meta tags using PHP.

view-source:https://www.heinsoe.com

***index.php***

```
<html>
    <head>
    <?php include './myMata.php';?>
    //more code
```

***myMata.php***

```
<?php
$path =  parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$paths = (explode("/", $path));
if (isset($paths[1])) {
    switch ($paths[1]) {
        case 'blog':
            ?>
            <title>dynamic title</title>
            //..... other tag
            <?php
            break;
        case 'contact':
            ?>
            <title>contact</title>
            //..... other tag
            <?php
            break;
        default:
            http_response_code(404);
            break;
    }
}
else{ 
    ?>
    <title>Home</title>
    //..... other tag
    <?php
}
?>
```