# Is there away to add dynamic social media meta tags to React app without SSR?

Tags: reactjs, web, seo, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I am looking to incorporate social media sharing for my website's URLs, such as blog posts, on platforms like Facebook and Twitter. I have learned that libraries like **react-helmet** can be used to modify meta tags. However, I have also learned that Facebook and Twitter's crawlers do not support the rendering of JavaScript, which means the meta tags do not display when a blog post from my website is shared on these platforms. Is there an alternative solution that can be used without implementing Server-Side Rendering (SSR)?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71418866/4910154

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same for a while now. I have tried so many options and ways published online but all in vain. Switch to Next Js and get over it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34671893)